# Referring to the components of a vector within a sum

Tags: vector, summation, index

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, but....

I'm playing around, trying to do the standard deviation for my stats homework (don't worry, I already worked out the answer by hand), and I have

```
μ := 0.906
y = {0.343, 0.441, 0.189, 0.027}
Sqrt[\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∑\), \(i = 0\), \(3\)]\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\((i - μ)\), \(2\)]\ 
\*SubscriptBox[\(y\), \([i]\)]\)\)]
```

which looks like
    $ \sqrt{\sum _{i=0}^3 (i-\mu )^2 y_i} $

Now that looks like what I want, but it does not evaluate how I'd hope.

So I tried out $y_1$ on it's own, and just get the whole list followed by subscript 1, rather than the second (or third...) element.

Ok, so that's fine, if a little disappointing that I can't index into a vector as easily as that. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to cleanly achieve the goal of retrieving the ith element of a vector within an expression like this.

Comment: change the last line to `Sqrt[\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(3\)]\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\((i - \[Mu])\), \(2\)]\ 
\*SubscriptBox[\(y\), \([\([i]\)]\)]\)\)]`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: ... (1) in Mathematica indices start at `1`, not `0` (2) you need to use `[[i]]` to refer to `ith`  `Part` of a list, (3) `Part` syntax `y[[i]]` also works in subscripts. (4) Much simpler form `Sqrt[Sum[(i - \[Mu])^2 y[[i]], {i, 1, 4}]]` gives the same result.

Comment: kguler, thanks for the help. You don't want to put that as an answer? Also, I don't see how the second version would give the same result--: $ 1-\mu \neq 0-\mu $, right? or am I missing something

Comment: @Ben, if `i` in `i-\[Mu]` is the same as the part index, maybe you need to change the sum to `Sqrt[Sum[(i - 1 - \[Mu])^2 y[[i]], {i, 1, 4}]]`?

Comment: Sure, those both (subtracting 1 from i in the variance term when going 1--> 4 vs. subtracting 1 from the part index going 0-->3) produce the same output. Anyway, if you post your comments as an answer, I could accept it.

Comment: @Ben just posted the comments above as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can get the desired result using much simpler form

```
Sqrt[Sum[(i - 1 - μ)^2 y[[i]], {i, 1, 4}]]
(* 0.793748 *)
```

Notes on your code:

In *Mathematica* indices start at `1`, not `0`. Furthermore, you need to use `y[[i]]` to refer to *ith* `Part` of a list `y`, not `y[i]`. With these changes

```
Sqrt[\!\( \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∑\), 
 \(i = 1\), \(4\)]\( \*SuperscriptBox[\((i - 1 - μ)\), 
 \(2\)]\ \*SubscriptBox[\(y\), \([\([i]\)]\)]\)\)]
```

also gives `0.793748`.

Finally, if you have to, you can use part indices as subscripts using, for example, `Esc[[Esc 2 Esc]]Esc` for `Part` 2.

Answer (score 1):

If what you wish to calculate is $\sqrt{\sum _{i=0}^3 (i-\mu )^2 y_i}$, this can be done:

```
Sqrt@Total[(Range[0, 3] - μ)^2 y]
```

which gives 0.793748. The function `Range[0,3]` gives the numbers {0,1,2,3}, each of which is subtracted from mu and squared. These are then multiplied by the corresponding element of `y` and the collection is summed using `Total`.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. Not the answer to the question, which is about how to access list elements via index, but I've no doubt I'll be using Range and Total in the future

Comment: @Ben -- I think the point is that it is often better (when programing in Mathematica) to *not* express formulas in an index-by-index fashion, but rather to use operations on the vectors/lists.

Comment: No doubt that's true. And I anticipate vectorizing my solutions and programming in a generally functional style when writing full-blown programs. For the time being, though, my purpose is to use the symbolic tools here to learn calculus (and statistics), not to optimize my code.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way to index (not as concise as kguler) but may be useful to note is [`MapIndexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html):

```
Sqrt[Total @ MapIndexed[(#2[[1]] - 1 - μ)^2 #1 &, y]]
```

yielding 0.793748

- `#2` is the index starting at {1}, hence need for `#2[[1]]`
- lists/arrays start at 1, so reindexing -> `#2[[1]]-1` as per kguler